# avoiding setTimeOut loop multiple instances

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function like so:

https://jsfiddle.net/pjngaffo/1/

```
i=0;
function refreshInfos() {
    if($('.main_dialog').length > 0) {
            console.log('loop-->',i++);
        setTimeout(function(){refreshManager()},1000);
    }
}

$('.main_dialog').on('click',function(){
    refreshInfos();
});

function refreshManager(){
//do stuff
//then call refreshInfos() for automatisation purposes
refreshInfos();
}
```

As you can see, if I click on the button **"click -> console"** there is multiple instances of the function `refreshInfos()`.

My question is, how can I call that function (anywhere I'll need it) to makes the other instances stop/destroy?

Comment: `var stop = false` then inside refreshInfos `if(stop) return; //TERMINATE`

Comment: Where do I set stop to false? I tried to set it on the click or into refreshManager() but its just terminate the loop forever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@priyadarshi swain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6667276/priyadarshi-swain) answered you need to use `clearTimeout()`

**1st:** save `setTimeout()` to the global variable to allow you to clear the timer later

**2nd:** create another function to stop the timer *and reset the `i` variable to 0 as well*

**3rd:** you'll need to always call the stop timer function before run timer function

Here's how you can do this

```js
var i = 0 , timer = 0;   // set timer as a global variable
function refreshInfos() {
    if($('.main_dialog').length > 0) {
        console.log('loop-->',i++);
        timer = setTimeout(function(){refreshManager()},1000);  // save it to timer variable
    }
}

// another function to stop the timer
function StoprefreshInfos(){ 
  clearTimeout(timer);  // clear the timer
  i = 0;   // reset i variable to 0
}
$('.main_dialog').on('click',function(){
  StoprefreshInfos();  // run the stop timer function before refresh info function
  refreshInfos();  // then run the refresh info function
});

// button click to just test and stop the timer
$('.stop').on('click',function(){
  StoprefreshInfos();  // stop the timer function
});

function refreshManager(){
//do stuff
//then call refreshInfos() for automatisation purposes
refreshInfos();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='main_dialog' style="border:1px solid #333">

  click -> console

</div>
<div class='main_dialog' style="border:1px solid #333">

  click -> console

</div>
<button class="stop">Stop Timer</button>
```

> **Note:** while `refreshInfos();` run inside `refreshManager()` and you're using `setTimeout(function(){refreshManager()},1000);` this
>   code will refresh the `refreshInfos();` so I didn't find a good way to
>   clear the timer inside the `refreshInfos();` function .. and instead I
>   create another function to stop the timer

Comment: Nice! Thanks alot, that is working like a charm. I was confused with how to use @priyadarshi answer, but now it's clear. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use window.clearTimeout() to stop excution.

```
 var timeout = setTimeout(function(){refreshManager()},1000); 
 window.clearTimeout(timeout);
```

Comment: If I put window.clearTimeout(timeout); into refreshInfos, it's not a loop anymore, and if I put it before the call into the click function or refreshManager(), it create an error "timeout is not defined"